# SL4: overlaping children in a grid

Tags: silverlight, grid, overlap

Is there a way to know in a grid if 2 children are overlapping each other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the blog post here by Andy Beaulieu. He describes the various collision detection methods in Silverlight. It's for Silverlight 3, but the majority of the article will be applicable. http://www.andybeaulieu.com/Home/tabid/67/EntryID/160/Default.aspx

Comment: Well i'll start from his solution and create my own. Thx for the help

Answer (score 0):

maybe, when the left margin of the first control + width of the first control + right margin of the second control + width of the second control > the width of the grid? :)